# AuthorizedKeysCommand in OpenSSH without user

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to configure OpenSSH to invoke the [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5) without a matching user being registered locally on the host machine?

Comment: What would you expect `sshd` to do upon successful authentication? The user name would still not be valid, so who would it run as after successful authentication?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "a user not being registered in the host machine"? A user can be available from a remote source. Or do you mean a user not available _at all_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean a non-local user, yes, it is perfectly possible, `freeIPA`, for example, can store users' public keys in its LDAP backend:

```
ipa user-mod user –sshpubkey='ssh-rsa AAAA…'
```

and uses:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` effectively delegating the validation of authorized keys to `sssd', which in turn is configured to contact the freeIPA server.

References from the [`freeIPA`](https://www.freeipa.org/) site [here](https://www.freeipa.org/images/1/10/Freeipa30_SSSD_OpenSSH_integration.pdf).

Comment: I can only get the AuthorizedKeysCommand to fire if a local user exists.  Is there perhaps a conflicting setting somewhere else that I haven't been able to pin down?

Comment: It depends on how users are looked up in your system, are you using `sssd`, plain LDAP, any other? what's in the `passwd` line in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Thanks @dawud, the Name Service Switch configuration was the piece I was missing.

Comment: @dawud @chadmaughan I am having the same issue and am not clear on what changes were necessary in nsswitch.conf.  I currently have `passwd:    compat systemd`.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

`sshd` cannot authenticate users that do not exist according to the system it is running on. The user must exist, though they need not be defined locally.